# Add all interactions among categorical variables in lasso in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, interaction, lasso-regression

I want to add all possible interactions among the eight variables, which are all categorical. My dataset looks like following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ersee.png)

I use `as.formula` to include all interactions. My code is below

```
f = as.formula(y ~ .^8)
x = model.matrix(f, data)[, -1]
y = data$y
```

However, my `x` becomes following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfG09.png)

And there are 6560 columns in total. I have no idea why it becomes this. Isn't it should still be `1, 2, 3` in `x` variables? May I ask how I should fix this or interpret this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have eight variables each with three levels.  You want to include every possible interaction, that is every possible combination of the eight factors.

There are 3^8 different possible combinations of values for your predictors.  So there are 3^8=6561 possible main effects and interactions (including the intercept) in your design matrix.

To see how they are encoded consider a single 3-level predictor:

```
> model.matrix(lm(y ~ x1))
  (Intercept) x12 x13
1           1   0   0
2           1   1   0
3           1   0   1
```

A single 3 level factor is encoded as 3 columns, an intercept plus two dummy variables.

Now add a second 3-level predictor and their interaction:

```
> model.matrix(lm(y ~ (x1+x2)^2))
  (Intercept) x12 x13 x22 x23 x12:x22 x13:x22 x12:x23 x13:x23
1           1   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0
2           1   1   0   1   0       1       0       0       0
3           1   0   1   0   0       0       0       0       0
```

So here there are 9 permissable combinations of those binary variables.  When you get up to 8 variables, each of your 6561 possible combinations of predictors is represented by permissable combinations of these binary variables.  (obviously you can't have both `x12` and `x13` positive at the same time).

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes sense to me!